# Find specific time in excel sheet and insert it in specific row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In `Table 1`, I have four columns:

```
------------------------------------
| A        | B        | C   | D    |
|----------------------------------|
| 1/9/2016 | 7:47:48  | x1  | in   |
| 1/9/2016 | 7:56:40  | x2  | in   |
| 1/9/2016 | 7:58:58  | x3  | in   |
| 1/9/2016 | 16:35:35 | x2  | out  |
| 1/9/2016 | 16:58:31 | x3  | out  |
| 1/9/2016 | 16:10:17 | x1  | out  |
| ...      |          |     |      |
| 2/9/2016 | 8:10:44  | x1  | in   |
| 2/9/2016 | 8:00:40  | x2  | in   |
| 2/9/2016 | 7:59:53  | x3  | in   |
| 2/9/2016 | 17:02:35 | x1  | out  |
| 2/9/2016 | 16:17:22 | x2  | out  |
| 2/9/2016 | 16:34:53 | x3  | out  |
------------------------------------
```

In `Table 2`, I have three columns:

- E: date of a month
- F: in time for x1 on that date
- G: out time for x1 on that date.

Which formula to put in columns `F` and `G` so that I can get results like this from `Table 1`:

```
---------------------------------
| E        | F       | G        |
|-------------------------------|
| 1/9/2016 | 7:47:48 | 16:10:17 |
| 2/9/2016 | 8:10:44 | 17:02:35 |
---------------------------------
```

I have tried this formula:

```
=IF(C1="x1", VLOOKUP(B1,A1:D9,2,FALSE)," ")<br/>
```

but I get `#N/A` error.

With this formula:

```
=IF(AND(C1="x1",D1="In",A1=E1),B1," ")
```

I get a blank cell.

Comment: Post your VLOOKUP formula in your question, perhaps it was used incorrectly.

Comment: use `=IF(C1="x1",B1," ")` instead and make sure the cell formatting of the cell where you enter this formula it set properly to a time format?

Comment: Let me see if I understand. It sounds like you have multiple conditions needing to be met. You need to return the time from B, if `C=x1` AND `D="in"` AND `A={specific date}`? Is that correct?

Comment: @thilinaR yes, thank you, but, I have to find all times when x1 was in this specific month (date 1.9.16. is just example) ,a nd also when he was out this month.. so I can't unify this formula to all dates, I will have to change each one manualy..

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Can you please add another table at the bottom but fill out column E with an example of the results. This will help us to fully understand.

Comment: @Dave all I get in column E in each row is:  #N/A  when using above formula..

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking you edit your post and show us what you'd like to see in Column E :) Also Can there only be a maximum of 2 x1 and 2 x2 and 2 x3 etc?

Comment: you've shared a lot of information in comments and it's very difficult to follow, please edit your question and include all those information to make it easier to follow.

Comment: how about `=IF(AND(C1="x1",D1="in",MONTH(A1)=9),B1," ")` and drag it down? u can replace 9 with any other number u need or use `=IF(AND(C1="x1",D1="in",MONTH(NOW())=MONTH(A1)),B1," ")` if you always want the current month

Comment: ok. i see that the question has been updated with several other columns. please state clearly in the question in point form (1) what results you are looking for and all the conditions that need to be met to calculate the results

Comment: if x1 can appear multiple times in the same month, part of the answer will need to have a count function that returns how many x1 there are.  This starts to get quite clumsy once have a variable and not fixed number of entries that are being searched for. It is still doable, but can be tough.  Usually to my users I recommend looking at where the data is coming from and where it goes or is used to see if can find a better data flow.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create a column before all the columns in `Table 1`.

i.e. Column `A` will be this new column.

To populate the values in column `A`, on cell `A1`, type `=B1&D1&E1` and drag it down to all the other rows till the end of data in `Table 1`.

Note: After adding this as column `A`, the the formulas below reference the updated columns.

i.e. your previous columns in `Table 2`: `E`, `F`, `G` will change to `F`, `G`, `H` and you will have dates on column `F` and be entering `VLOOKUP` formulas in columns `G` and `H`.

---

**Step 2:** Perform a `VLOOKUP` on cell `G1`, using the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($F1&"x1"&"in",A:E,3,FALSE)
```

---

**Step 3:** Perform a `VLOOKUP` on cell `H1`, using the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($F1&"x1"&"out",A:E,3,FALSE)
```

Comment: (1) which column are you getting the `#N/A` error on? Column `G` or column `H` or both? Do you get `#N/A` for all rows or just some of them? (2) Is the formatting on the dates in column `B` and column `F` correct? (use format painter to copy formatting so that its identical. You can also copy/paste the dates that you want from column `B` to column `F` to make sure they are identical

Comment: Also, here is a link with the sample data working with the formulas above. Make sure you **download** the file and open from your desktop to view it correctly. https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2cocyyw0abnsow/test.xlsx?dl=0